# Pandas, turn list of lists of tuples into DataFrame awkward column headers.

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from parsed addresses that I obtained from the usaddress python library: https://github.com/datamade/usaddress

The data is a list of lists of tuples. Each address has a list like this associated with it:

```
[('Robie', 'BuildingName'),
('House,', 'BuildingName'),
('5757', 'AddressNumber'),
('South', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'),
('Woodlawn', 'StreetName'),
('Avenue,', 'StreetNamePostType'),
('Chicago,', 'PlaceName'),
('IL', 'StateName'),
('60637', 'ZipCode')]
```

However, for some addresses a certain field may, or may not be present. I want to export this data into a pandas DataFrame with all the column headers (BuildingName, Address...ect) and if that that column header isn't present in the list, then the cell is just left blank.

What I have at the moment is:

```
newAddr = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    newAddr.append(usaddr.parse(row['FullAddress']))

df2 = DataFrame(newAddr)
```

But this produces a file with no column headers and no real organization by column, since the missing values just shift everything over.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need to do some cleaning first. There is at least a known instance of overlapping data, 'BuildingName' from the list of tuples above, and you risk overwriting multiple times the cells in the same rows. You might thus want to iterate over the second element in each tuple and produce a dictionary of the available column names, counting how many times they appear per row. If they appear more than once per row, you may have to inspect the data manually

Comment: I found a way around the issue of overlapping data. The tag function rather than the parse function attempts to concatenate parts of the address with the same tag. However sometimes it will throw an exception when doing so. With some exception handling this is fine. I don't know what I want to do yet in the case of an exception but for now something simple will do.This brings me back to the issue of creating the proper column header organization.The tag function outputs the data as an ordered dictionary though. This changes things a bit.

Comment: If you can confirm that no second element in each tuple is repeated more than once per row, you can try this: `all_rows = dict()`
`for row in mylist:`
    `for couple in row:`
        `if couple[1] in all_rows:`
            `all_rows[couple[1]].append(couple[0])`
        `else:`
            `all_rows[couple[1]] = [couple[0]]`
`df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)`. If this solution fits your problem, please remove the second tuple from the list above provided as an example, because it would throw an error otherwise. There is no way out of removing double entries in each row I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- You use `usaddress.tag`
- have ways to handle the errors that may be raised from `usaddress.tag`
- only want the first part of the return from `usaddress.tag`

Then, you can do the following

```
import usaddress
import pandas as pd

# your list of addresses dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('PATH_TO_ADDRESS_CSV')

# list of orderedDict
ordered_dicts = []

# loop through addresses and get respective information
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # here you should try/except for cases that fail
    addr = usaddress.tag(row['FullAddress'])

    # append to list
    ordered_dicts.append(addr[0])

# **get all relevant keys in your list
cols = set().union(*(d.keys() for d in ordered_dicts))

# create new dataframe
df_new = pd.DataFrame(ordered_dicts, columns=cols)

df_new.to_csv('PATH_TO_DESIRED_CSV_ENDPOINT')
```

The `**` represents an alternative solution to this part of the function. Because we know exactly all the columns that the `.tag` function can return, you can just initially set the columns as such (see all tags [here](https://github.com/datamade/usaddress/blob/master/training/README.md) and API [here](https://parserator.datamade.us/api-docs)):

```
cols = ['AddressNumberPrefix', 'AddressNumber', ...]
```

I hope this helps! Know that when you do `pd.DataFrame` with dictionaries and specify exact columns, it will automatically fill in the non-existing keys with `pd.NaN`.